# Use apollo-link to fetch a query upon any mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-link

I am working on an application where there are projects with a nested tree of assets. In the backend, the changed-date of the project is updated when one of the children of grandchildren (or grand-grand-children) is updated.

In react-apollo, I have set-up all queries such that the updated object is returned and the cache of apollo is updated with the updated data. But I would also like to update the changed-date of the project (which may be a parent, grandparent, etc).

One solution is to use the refetchQueries option. However, that would mean I need to implement this refetchQueries option in all pieces where the useMutation hook is used, which causes a lot of code duplication plus the risk that it may be forgotten by other developers (team of 4). A better option is to create a custom hook that wraps the useMutation hook, but devs still need to use it.

So I am now looking at using apollo-link for this, which will affect all mutations performed. However, I can't figure out if it is possible to add a query to the operation, or to queue a query, and if possible - how to do it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using ApolloLink you could generate linked `afterware` to parse returned responses, and conditionally update the cache in appropriate cases.

```
    import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";
    import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
 
    const httpLink = createHttpLink({ uri: "/graphql" });
    const updateDateCacheLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
       return forward(operation).map(response => {
           const context = operation.getContext();
           const { response: { headers } } = context;
    
           /* conditionally update cache */     

         return response;
     });
   });
 
    // use with apollo-client
    const link = updateDateCacheLink.concat(httpLink);
```

---

Alternatively, you might consider using a HOC returning a component that implements the `update` callback of `useMutation`, which receives the update payload. This would avoid duplication and encapsulate the common caching logic consistent with your request. And as you noted a custom hook could wrap and be used in place of useMutation (not shown below).

```
const withMutationCacheUpdate = args => Wrapped => {
  return function(props) {
    const [updateData] = useMutation(UPDATE_DATA, {
      update(cache, { data: { newData } }) {
        // Read relevant data from cache with cache.readQuery,
        // then update using cache.writeQuery, cache.writeFragment 
       // or cache.modify as appropriate with returned payload and possibly args
      },
    })
    return <Wrapped {...props} updateData={updateData} />
  }
}

const config = {...}
const YourComponent = props => { ... }
const YourWrappedComponent = withMutationCacheUpdate(config)(YourComponent)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, my hope was that it would be possible to actually add another query (i.e. "query { projects { changed } }") whenever an mutation is made. So that the returned response is actually more than specified in the mutation-query.

But I believe this is not possible, after many searches on the internet. So I have now provided a new custom hook that always performs an additional quer using the "refetchQueries" option.

We will use this custom hook as a drop-in replacement of "useMutation"